# Replace between two characters

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I want to remove a string that is between two characters, let's say for example I want to replace all characters of the string between `"value="` and `" "` with `""` so value will always equal "";

Example:

```
"<input value=98 name=anything>"
```

To this

```
"<input value= name=anything>"
```

How could I do it in JavaScript?

Comment: Yes it's just for a simple comparision test for some inputs with any value, ignore how bad the HTML is, I just want value to always =""

Comment: are you using any specific javascript library ?

Comment: Ummm... is this a string manipulation question or DOM manipulation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably use regular expressions here, if the structure of the HTML is always like this.

But it would get more complicated if you had to consider `value=foo`, `value="foo"` or `value="foo bar"` too.

Here is a more exciting way, which would work with any kind of HTML string and `value`:

```
var tmp_ = document.createElement('div');
tmp_.innerHTML = htmlString;
tmp_.children[0].setAttribute('value', '');

htmlString = tmp_.innerHTML;
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/9JusW/)

Comment: Please could you please do a regex as it is a string I am manipulating NOT the actual HTML...

Comment: @JamesRattray: `htmlString` is your HTML string. Haven't you had a look at the demo? The idea is to parse the string into DOM to manipulate it more easily.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest not using a regex for this, but, instead, some pretty simple JavaScript:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
alert(inputs.length);
for (i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
    //inputs[i].setAttribute('value',''); or you can use the following line instead...
    inputs[i].value = '';
}
```

1. [JS Fiddle demo (using first line)](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hr635/2/).
2. [JS Fiddle demo (using second line)](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/hr635/1/).

Comment: Please could you do a regex as it is a string I am manipulating NOT the actual HTML...

Comment: Where is the string coming from? Will it be turned into html in a/the page? Please post the code showing the string creation.

Comment: It's gotten from some ajax thing, but to compare it to original input I want value to always = "" -so value can change but other attributes cannot (like disabled for example)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using javascript libraries:

Mootools version:

let say you have a field with the id=test , you can do the following :

```
$('test').set('value','');
```

Jquery version:

```
$("#test").val("");
```